Create scatteredInterpolant for data with double value points
I have tabulated data, containing fluid properties, that I want to use for interpolation. The grid itself is not regular on some points, so I want to use scatteredInterpolant for interpolation.
Unfortunately, on some grid points I have two values that are then automatically removed or collapsed by scatteredInterpolant. However I want to preserve those as the vertical rise is necessary to maintain. I investigated groupsummary if this could help but I am not sure how to use it properly.
For me it would be acceptable if I could slightly distance the grid points and use an interpolated value for both grid points, one on the low side, the other on the high side and to have a steep rise instead of a vertical rise but I have no clue how to do it.
The thing is the points where this vertical rise exist are pretty scattered and I have several tables with this so manually it might by a bit hard to do.
Has anybody a good idea how to deal with this?
Example (simplified) of my data:
x     y     values   state
1     2     10       liquid
2     2     11       liquid
3     2     10.5     liquid
3     2     200      gaseous
4     2     202      gaseous
5     2     203      gaseous
1     3     9        liquid
2     3     9.9      liquid
3.1   3     10.8     liquid
3.1   3     195      gaseous
4     3     199      gaseous
5     3     201.5    gaseous
1     4     8.9      liquid
2     4     9.5      liquid
3.3   4     10.2     liquid
3.3   4     185      gaseous
4     4     191      gaseous
5     4     199      gaseous

I have this data in a struct variable, put x, y, and v in an array and tried to interpolate like this:
F = scatteredInterpolant(x,y,v);

For me it would be acceptable to modify the doubling where x collapses as follows explained for point x1 = 3.1 and y1 = 2:
I create a point x1.1 at let's say 3.0999, y1.1 = y1 = 2 and interpolate v1.1 by using as values (2,2) and (3.1,2).
This new point would replace the point (3.1,2,liquid).
Any other approach or solution would be fine, too!

It seems that all your double (x, y) pairs coincide with a phase change. Are you sure you want to mix those, i.e. interpolate them together? Otherwise, your proposed solution sounds reasonable. Find double pairs (use tolerance!), add or subtract your desired "small interval" and interpolate. (Sorry about the editing clash, I had just finished the small grammar+markdown tweaks when your edit popped in)

yeah, I am currently thinking if I should not use groupsummary to make several tables depending on state. The issue is I want to use this table or tables in a larger simulation environment where I have fluid that potentially might change its state and I want to keep computational load low. I would have first to check at each step about the state of the fluid which would be a sort of challenge already in order to decide which table to take... So it might be faster with my initial idea but I really want to automatise this as the database is huge.

Since your x and y are sorted in a sensible way, you should just be able to increment x at all points where the previous x value was the same, and the previous y value was the same.
In a loop this would be something like
ofst = 0.0001; % amount to increase duplicate axis values by
for ii = 2:numel(x)
    if (x(ii)<=x(ii-1)) && (y(ii)==y(ii-1))
        x(ii) = x(ii) + ofst;
    end
end

Without a loop it could be something like this, but be wary this wouldn't handle the edge-case where adding the offset could make one x value larger than the next one. The loop did handle this edge case by using <= and checking sequentially.
ofst = 0.0001;
bofst = [false; (diff(x)==0) & (diff(y)==0)];
x = x + bofst*ofst;


Do I understand correctly that for your first code you add the offset to all x that are below the points where a doubling occurs? If so would this not lead to have again the same issue as soon as I have the condition met several times in my data?

@ManyQuestions The loop goes through each point in the array, if the value of x and y at that point is the same as the previous point then x is increased slightly. At each loop iteration only the value in position ii is modified. Give it a try on your example to see what the result is

I tried and it works as intended. Can I ask a further question? In your code there is the "smaller than" sign in the if clause. To my understanding this works because x is increasing. If it were decreasing, would this still work?

The <= is to handle the described edge case, imagine you have ofst=0.1 and x=[3,3,3] then after ii=2 you have x=[3,3.1,3], and when ii=3 the neighbouring values are no longer equal to each other, but you still want to make the 3rd element bigger than the 2nd one! So x(3)<=x(2) is true and we get x=[3,3.1,3.2]. If your x values were decreasing then you'd want to check the opposite condition >= so that [3,3,3] becomes [3,2.9,3] and then [3,2.9,2.8] during the loop, decreasing x(ii) if x(ii)>=x(ii-1). The y check could really just be == as y is not modified
